# How do i get something like this done in flutter. Its a table that whatever is inputted in the admin app will reflect here. How do i build this?

Tags: flutter

What I want to replicate with flutter

[image]

[What I have done so far](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pxv2ChVOnpwBNbWLaJoc1r4X7vvDHib8/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Please add your code to your question. I don't understand on what basis the list changes when I select an item in the leading.

Comment: Try using firestore with steam builder